# Drop rows from each group if dates are within a given range

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, group-by

Given a DataFrame like below:

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({"ID":["A", "A", "C" ,"B", "B"], 
                    "date":["01/01/2014","01/31/2014","01/23/2014","01/01/2014","01/20/2014"]})
```

I want to remove "duplicates". "duplicates" are defined as those rows where the ID of the rows are the same, but the "date" between them is Less Than 30 days.

The resulting DataFrame upon removal of the "duplicates" is expected appear as:

```
ID    date
A   01/01/2014
A   01/31/2014
C   01/23/2014
B   01/01/2014
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Convert `date` to datetime.
2. Group `date` by `ID` and find difference between consecutive rows
3. Extract the days component from the `timedelta` difference and compare it to 30
4. Filter `dfx` based on the mask

```
dfx[~pd.to_datetime(dfx.date).groupby(dfx.ID).diff().dt.days.lt(30)]

  ID        date
0  A  01/01/2014
1  A  01/31/2014
2  C  01/23/2014
3  B  01/01/2014
```